# Issues with @font-face

Tags: firefox, font-face

I am using the @font-face. I had to break it up into two section because firefox continued to use the first font and it showed up crappy. Actually it still displays blurry/pixelated in firefox. Any solutions for that? Anyways it all seems to work fine now, but I can't get any of the bold functions to work. Doesn't seem to matter where I add it in the code whether it is in the CSS or directly in the html it work make the font bolder. Is this normal?

```
@font-face {
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt;
src:url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), /* For IE */ 
    url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* For fix-IE */
    url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.woff') format('woff'), /* For new-IE */
    url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.otf') format('opentype'), /* For non-IE */
    url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.ttf') format('truetype'), /* For non-IE */
    url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.svg') format('svg'); /* For non-IE */
font-weight: bolder;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF;
src:url('../fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.otf') format('opentype'); /* For Firefox */
font-weight: bolder;
font-style: normal;
}
```

---

Comment: `weigt` should be `weight`

Comment: you're also using a bold font and declaring it as font-weight:normal

Answer (score 0):

Not all fonts have a bold spite that can render as bold.  You can try adjusting the `font-weight` in increments of 100 to see if that makes any difference.

Regarding Firefox using the first font, do you mean it was caching another font you used before?

Comment: I tried font-weight but it doesn't change anything. 

In regards to using the font first I was referring to .eot. Firefox chose to use that format of font instead of .otf. OTF display a bit more clearer in Firefox than the other formats, but it is still blurry/pixelated.

Comment: You misspelled weight. Double check that.